# SQL certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json

I keep getting the following error every time I try to run my Flight Booking application.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)'
> Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

this is the line of code that throws the error.

```
entities.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

I have tried changing the Connection Strings to

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Flights; Trusted_Connection=True; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

I am completely stumped on how to get the error to go away I have the correct IP in place, I have Trust Certificate checked, I have it set to allow connection but still nothing.

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: _"I have tried changing the Connection Strings to"_ - and? The  EF Core 7 [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true) is exactly about that. Verify that the new connection string with `Encrypt=False` is actually used.

Comment: how would I verify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just  had spent 4 hours trying to fix this error after moving to net 7. Tried to add to connection string "Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;" and several another triks. But in the end I  gave up and reinstalled EF core 6.15 and ef sql server 6.15.  Everything works properly. Don't waste your time trying to fix, ef 6.15 works with net 7. I don't know maybe net 7  works for a paid SQl server, but I am using a SQl Express too

Update

Use nuget package manager. Uninstal EF core  and server 7 if you have installed them. After this select 6.15 from DDL in the bottom and install this version

Comment: where would I do this reinstall and how would I get rid of the old core and server

Comment: You just saved the day man it worked like a charm when I changed the version my mental was crumbling before this thank you so much.

Comment: @ZayneGeffre You are welcome. I wish I knew it this morning too.

Comment: one of the million bugs of net 7, you are not alone @Serge